# How can I use list comprehension to separate values in a dictionary?

Tags: python

```
name=[]
age=[]
address=[]
...
for line in pg:
    for key,value in line.items():
        if key == 'name':
          name.append(value)
        elif key == 'age':
          age.append(value)
        elif key == 'address':
          address.append(value)
        .
        .
        .
```

Is it possible to use list comprehension for above code because I need to separate lots of value in the dict? I will use the lists to write to a text file.

#### Source Data:

```
a = [{'name': 'paul', 'age': '26.', 'address': 'AU', 'gender': 'male'},
     {'name': 'mei', 'age': '26.', 'address': 'NY', 'gender': 'female'},
     {'name': 'smith', 'age': '16.', 'address': 'NY', 'gender': 'male'},
     {'name': 'raj', 'age': '13.', 'address': 'IND', 'gender': 'male'}]
```

Comment: Can you please show what you’ve tried so far, and where you’ve gotten stuck?  Additionally, please show an example of your source data.

Comment: It seems you have more than one dict element with same key, am I right ?

Comment: @BradFigueroa yes, 'pg' is a list that have multiple dict with the same key. Wait, I post the list in the question

Answer (score 1):

I don't think list comprehension will be a wise choice because you have multiple lists.
Instead of making multiple lists and appending to them the value if the key matches you can use `defaultdict` to simplify your code.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for line in pg:
    for key, value in line.items():
        result[key].append(value)
```

You can get the name list by using `result.get('name')`

```
['paul', 'mei', 'smith', 'raj']
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't work the way you want: Your'e trying to assign the *three* different lists, so you would need three different comprehensions.  If your dict is large, this would roughly triple your execution time.

Something straightforward, such as

```
name = [value for for key,value in line.items() if key == "name"]
```

seems to be what you'd want ... three times.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as :

```
pg=[{"name":"name1","age":"age1","address":"address1"},{"name":"name2","age":"age2","address":"address2"}]

name=[v for line in pg for k,v in line.items() if k=="name"]
age=[v for line in pg for k,v in line.items() if k=="age"]
address=[v for line in pg for k,v in line.items() if k=="address"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really simple solution if you want to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

name = df['name'].tolist()
age = df['age'].tolist()
address = df['address'].tolist()

print(name)
print(age)
print(address)
```

#### Output:

```
['paul', 'mei', 'smith', 'raj']
['26.', '26.', '16.', '13.']
['AU', 'NY', 'NY', 'IND']
```

Additionally, if your end result is a text file, you can skip the list creation and write the `DataFrame` (or parts thereof) directly to a CSV with something as simple as:

```
df.to_csv('/path/to/output.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

In continuation with Vishal's answer, please dont use defaultdict. Using defaultdict is a very bad practice when you want to catch keyerrors. Please use setdefault.

```
results = dict()
for line in pg:
    for key, value in line.items():
        result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

Output

```
{
     'name': ['paul', 'mei', 'smith', 'raj'],
     'age': [26, 26, 26, 13],
      ...
}
```

However, note that if all dicts in pg dont have the same keys, you will lose the relation/correspondence between the items in the dict

Comment: That don't use default dict statement needs more evidence. I find it OK in use, and in my general reading of posts by others. Could it be that you had a painful but local debugging? Defaultdict is useful.

Comment: ```
   from collections import defaultdict

   results = defaultdict(list)

   print(results['abc'])
[]
```

For me, the above snippet is enough to avoid using `defaultdict` i.e accessing a key which doesn't exist returns a valid value. Unless you want this usage and are aware of the sideeffects, you shouldn't be using a defaultdict.

A common mistake is adding a key `address` and accidentally accessing `addres`. A  keyerror will catch your mistake, which doesnt happen with defaultdict

Comment: That seems to come down to the normal "use with due dilligence". There is a use where you *want* to capture all keys and a set difference down the line can categorise keys in a more meaningful manner. No, Vishals's answer seems fine, and your comment on defaultdict way too harsh.

Comment: Let us agree to disagree then :). I would never recommend defaultdict to a python beginner who are not aware of the side effect.

Comment: This can be an ideal time to introduce the OP to defaultdict. They have a *personal* problem. Vishal, shows them a neat solution with defaultdict. They may have more motivation to learn about it and for that learning to stick as it is of immediate use. Yes, we do disagree Ehtesham: but it's good that we are having an amicable discourse :-).